# ExactTarget not requesting config.json for custom Journey Builder Platform Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, platform-activity

I've more or less successfully configured two custom platform activities for Desk.com as per [Custom Activities - Desk.com API](https://github.com/sfmc-developer-advocates/custom-activity-deskapi-node).

They both appear in the journey builder activities:

[image: Custom Journey Builder platform activities]

After configuring an additional journey builder activity there is no change to the available Activities.
[image]

The newest ExactDev activity differs in that the Endpoint URL is to our own testing server: `https://exactdev.company.com/CasePage` (changed the domain to 'company' as I'd prefer the dev server not get picked up by bots). It was created following the steps in [Defining our Activity App Extension (still in App Center)](https://github.com/sfmc-developer-advocates/custom-activity-deskapi-node#defining-our-activity-app-extension-still-in-app-center). The key was also changed to be unique.

I confirmed that:

- https://exactdev.company.com/CasePage/index.html exists
- https://exactdev.company.com/CasePage/config.json exists
- the contents of the config.json file passes online linters, such as http://jsonlint.com/

Still, there is no sign in the web servers logs that a request has come in from ExactTarget for the config.json file when Journey Builder is opened for an interaction.

In Chrome's developer tools network tab I can see an indirect request for the config.json file for each of the Desk.com activities.
[image]

I tried manually creating the same request for my Endpoint URL:
https://jbinteractions.exacttargetapps.com/configjson/https%3A%2F%2Fexactdev.company.com%2FCasePage

With this the GET request did appear in the web server logs from an IP address that whois identifies as ExactTarget.

> 2015-04-01 20:37:19 192.168.1.1 GET /CasePage/config.json - 443 - 68.232.203.57

Incidentally, I learned at this point that the site needs to be SSL on the default 443 port. Previously it was SSL over another port but the ExactTarget /configjson/ request would error out.

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

When editing the Journey Builder Activities the `Public Extension` setting is hiding down the page.

[image]

I needed to change it from "This extension is available for: Only this application" to "This application and other installed applications".

[image]

Also, make sure you are using the default SSL port 443.